# Can you kill the man in white during the Citra's Dream sequence with an RPG?

Tags: far-cry-3

I dont know what was in that bottle Citra gave me but it must've been pretty fantastic because I found myself falling and then I was at at a poker table.  The other players disappeared and then I was standing with a man in white ahead of me. I knew...I just *knew* that he held the key to my destiny as a Rakyat Warriot.

I immediately turned and walked the other way.

Well, it turns out that if you walk far enough away from him, you get your guns back. I figured it's my hallucination and I should be able to murder whoever I want to, so I started shooting at the man in white. My SMG and shotgun didn't have nearly the range necessary, but it was an easy shot with a scoped sniper rifle...except that the rifle wouldn't fire when he was in the crosshairs! I could put rounds above, left, and right of him, but I couldn't shoot when shooting would result in him getting hit.

My next thought was to try splash damage from an RPG, but I didn't have one in my inventory. Since it doesn't seem likely that I'll be able to get back into the dream in this playthrough, **is it possible to kill the Man in White with an RPG during the dream sequence?**

Comment: I think my favorite part of the whole thing was waking up in the Rakyat temple with three empty guns and noticing that the Rakyat warriors were suddenly acting extremely respectful toward me.